# Simple introduction to linear models in R -

Tags: r

It was hard for me to understand linear models in R. There are a lot of documents for the case, but many of them are technical manuals rather than teaching the concept.

I found [this article](http://users.monash.edu.au/~murray/stats/BIO4200/LinearModels.pdf) really simple and instructive, I hope it would be useful for the other people who have the same problem.

Do you have any better suggestion?

Comment: I suggest understanding linear models before using them in R. There are quite a few good books on that topic. Once you are comfortable with the statistics understanding the implementations in R should be easy.

Comment: This is not a programming technical question. It is probably better suited for crossvalidated.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check [here](http://data.princeton.edu/R/linearModels.html) or [Linear Mixed Model](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-mixed-models.pdf), its also simple and easy to understand.